# Interpolation of the Möbius function

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-function

The Möbius function $\mu (n)$ can be computed using
$$\mu (n)=\sum_{\stackrel{1\le k \le n }{ \gcd(k,\,n)=1}} e^{2\pi i \frac{k}{n}}$$
(from *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* by Hardy and Wright). Maybe there is a fromula for the Möbius function which does not use the notion of divisibility. Can the Möbius function be interpolated by some analytic function?

Comment: Not from this formula I'd say. There is [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3493770/276986) with some interesting arithmetical/analytical meaning. Note that every sequence can be interpolated by many entire functions ($\sin(\pi x)$ vanishes at the integers and $\sin(\pi x)/x$ is non-zero only once)

Comment: Actually the formula you provided is sufficient for me.