# Is it possible to extend the prime counting function $\pi(x)$ to all real numbers like with the factorials?

Tags: number-theory

I'm a student and I'm really interested if you could potentially extend the prime counting function denoted as $\pi(x)$ to all real numbers (and possibly complex numbers), to do exactly what we did with the factorials. We extended them to fractions, irrationals and trancendental numbers. For example $2.28!=2.62\ldots$ and $\pi!=7.188\ldots$. The next sentences we will be to explain how the factorials were extended and how we could possibly use that into $\pi(x)$.
So we did this: to extend the factorial function we have to find all functions that satisfy this properties

- it has to pass through $0!=1$, $1!=1$, $2!=2$, $3!=6$, $4!=24$ and so on on every positive integer from which it follows that
- all points on the function has to satisfy this equation $(x+n)!=x!
  \prod\nolimits_{k = 1}^n (x + k)$

So there is only one curve that satisfy this properties and that's how we found to extend of the factorial.

So can something like that be done to extend $\pi(x)$. We can find properties like it passes through every prime. I found a formula that extends it to negative numbers but I haven't program it yet because I can't program and I'm still checking the validity of it but for now it holds. So this is my end question: is it possible (I'm not asking how to do it, I'm asking if it's even possible(are there any functions that satisfy $\pi(x)$ conditions or are there none)) to extend $\pi(x)$ to all real numbers?

Comment: It's always possible to interpolate between values...piecewise linear interpolation is at least continuous, but of course there are many other continuous interpolators.  With the Gamma interpolation, we can require the factorial like property that $\Gamma(x+1)=x\times \Gamma(x)$ to specify the interpolation... are there any such properties for $\pi(x)$ that you want to preserve?

Comment: To be clear:  even the functional equation doesn't specify the interpolator uniquely.

Comment: Here is a [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to help you properly format your question.

Answer (score 3):

The prime counting function is defined as

$$\pi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & n\in \mathbb{P} \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{1}$$

which is valid for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

The sum is over all positive integer values of $n\le x$. Since the $\le$ operator is only valid for the reals, $\pi(x)$ defined in formula (1) above is undefined when $\Im(x)\ne 0$.

---

I suppose one do something like

$$\hat{\pi}(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{|x|} \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & n\in \mathbb{P} \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}$$

which evaluates similar to formula (1) above for $x>-2$, but this doesn't really seem very useful.

---

It's worth noting there are [explicit formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_for_L-functions#Riemann%27s_explicit_formula) for Riemann's prime-power counting function

$$\Pi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)} \frac{1}{n}\ \pi\left(x^{1/n}\right)\tag{3}$$

and the second Chebyshev function

$$\psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \Lambda(n)\tag{4}.$$

---

The explicit formula for $\pi(x)$ is derived from the explicit formula for $\Pi(x)$ via Möbius inversion of formula (3) above:

$$\pi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}\ \Pi\left(x^{1/n}\right)\tag{5}.$$

---

The explicit formulas mentioned above only converge for $x>1$, but I believe the alternate representation

$$\pi_o(x)=\underset{N,f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a(n) \left(\frac{x}{n}-\frac{\text{Si}(2 \pi f x)}{\pi}+\frac{\sin(2 \pi f x)}{2 \pi f n}+\frac{1}{\pi} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{f n-1} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{2 \pi k x}{n}\right)}{k}\right)\right)\tag{6}$$

converges to $\underset{\epsilon\to 0}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{\pi(x-\epsilon)+\pi(x+\epsilon)}{2}\right)$ for $x\ge 0$ and evaluates to an odd function of $x$. The arithmetic function $a(n)$ referenced in formula (6) above corresponds to [OEIS entry A143519](https://oeis.org/A143519).

---

Figure (1) below illustrates $\pi_o(x)$ defined in formula (6) above in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $\pi(x)$ defined in formula (1) above where formula (6) is evaluated at $N=50$ and $f=10$.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (6) ion orange overlaid on formula (1) in blue]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (6) for $\pi_o(x)$ (orange) overlaid on the blue reference function $\pi(x)$

---

Formula (6) for $\pi_o(x)$ above only converges for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, but I believe it might be possible to define an entire function which converges to the prime counting function $\pi(x)$ at non-negative integer values of $x$. This analytic function would not be unique and requires a bit more investigation. The approach is basically similar to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4160465) I posted to a question on an entire function interpolating the Möbius function $\mu(n)$. This linked answer is also the basis for formula (6) above.

---

Comment: That's great thank you. So I'm thinking I could make it a limit. There are a few definitions of the gamma function, one of which that includes a limit product defined by Euler. So I'm not looking for a specific function, I'm looking for a group of functions and I wou;ld them to hold the following properties:

Comment: 1. to pass through every prime number.   2. if n is an integer and x is a real number but not an integer then π(n)<π(x)<π(n+1) so that it looks like a step function. Also can anyone tell me if that's true and if so tell me more about it  p(n+1)-p(n)<70000000.

Comment: Also is it useful to extend the prime counting function. Would it help us figure out stuffs about primes.

Comment: @Euler-Masceroni I refined my answer above in an attempt to more fully address your question.